# Reference request: The set of all walks of finite length in a finite, strongly connected digraph is countable.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a finite, strongly connected directed graph. It seems evident to me that the set of all walks of finite length through $\mathcal{G}$ is countable, since walks can be enumerated first by path length, and for each path length by the set of all initial vertexes, and for every such set by the set of connected vertexes, and so on and so forth, in the same way that a language containing only finite strings can be enumerated.

1. Is my intuition here correct?
2. Is this result so obvious as to reasonably not require a reference in a doctoral thesis?
3. If a citation is needed, is there a reference that provides this result or a stronger result that implies it?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and I don’t think that it should require a reference as long as the thesis is in mathematics or a very closely related area.

Comment: Whether the result is considered obvious or not, I don't think it needs a reference; it is either obvious enough to be stated without a proof, or else you should give the very short proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is, in fact, obvious. Define a "walk of length $n$" to be a sequence of nodes $v_1, v_2, ..., v_{n + 1}$ such that there is an edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$, $v_2$ and $v_3$, etc.

Clearly, this is an infinite subset of the set of all sequences of nodes. And the set of all sequences of elements of a finite, non-empty set is always countably infinite.

Thus, the set of all walks will be countably infinite.

One would assume that any math or CS Ph.D. would realize this immediately, but you should ask your advisor whether you need a proof/citation, not the internet. Your advisor's opinion is the one that matters, not mine.